# basic java code to understand inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Why does the `System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());` prints the following:

```
Beta 44 <br/>
4 44          (notice this is in the second line)
```

I was expecting it to print something like this:

```
4 Beta 44 44   (this one is in one line)
```

The reason why I thought it would print this way is because we call `b.h` first which is 4.Then we call `b.getH()` which will print Beta 44 44

Here is the code:

```
class Baap{

        int h = 4;
        public int getH(){
                System.out.println("Beta " + h);
                return h;
        }
}

class Beta extends Baap{
        int h = 44;
        public int getH(){
                System.out.println("Beta " + h);
                return h;
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) {
                Baap b = new Beta();
                System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the call to `getH()` prints "Beta 44", since the argument of `System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH())` is evaluated before `println` is called.

Then `System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH())` prints "4 44".

`b.h` returns `4` because there is no overriding for instance variables, and since `b`'s compile time type is `Baap`, `b.h` returns the instance variable of the super class.

`b.getH()` returns `44` because you `b`'s runtime type is Beta, which overrides `getH()`.

Comment: thanks this explanation makes sense to me. (Stackoverflow won't let me accept the answr. i'll try again later)

Answer (score 2):

The output is because the expression inside `System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());` is evaluates first then printed.
So the order is

```
System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());  // calls getH() method
System.out.println("Beta " + h);           //print Beta 44
System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());  //prints 4 44
```

So the complete o/p is

```
Beta 44
4 44
```

`b.h` is `4` because variables are not inhreited so it called by reference ie `h` variable of `Baap` class.
`b.getH()` give you `44` value returned from `Beta` class method(h=44 in Beta class).

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());

This is executed in the following order:

```
String temp1 = b.h
String temp2 = temp1 + " "
String temp3 = b.getH () // prints Beta 44
String temp4 = temp2 + temp3
System.out.println (temp4) // prints 4 44
```

Answer (score 1):

Output is

> Beta 44
>
> 4 44

To evaluate expression `System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());` method `b.getH()` needs to get evaluated first. As the object is infact of class `Beta` you see `Beta 44` printed in 1st line [Since you are using `println` method you will have a new line character at the end] and the method returns 44.

Then it's as simple as `System.out.println(b.h + " " + 44);`

Now as you are just referring to a variable directly using the reference which is of type `Baap` you will get 4 [Remember variables are not overridden, they are just shadowed]. And hence the 2nd line `4 44`

Answer (score 1):

It first evaluates the expression in println() statement, because of that Beta44 gets printed first. then it starts printing values in println statement from left to right , then print 4,44. it prints 4 because the instance variable is of Baap type(compile time). So, it picks the value of variable defined in Baap class.
Only overridden methods are being called from child class if same method exists in both parent and child. But, variables and static fields are called from instance variable type which is Baap in this case.

Hope it will help.

Comment: it is a great answer and helpful

Answer (score 0):

It gives absolutly right answer

```
Beta 44 
4 44
```

for this statement:  `System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());`

As programm counter or compiler checked a statement from right to left and  in the println() method programm counter first identified and eveluted the method's argument , since it excutes first `b.getH()` 
 so `"Beat 44"` is the first part of the answer ,after that it gets a new line for `println()` and at last it print `b.h` value (4) and then return value of `b.getH()` which is 44.

Answer (score 0):

It is because same overridden method is used. When an overridden method is used then the class will give preference to its own method rather than parent's class method.