# OCAJP practice test

Tags: java

Please look at this code:

```
public class Baap {
    public int h = 4;

    public int geth() {
        System.out.println("Baap" + h);
        return h;
    }
}

public class Beta extends Baap {
    public int h = 44;

    public int geth() {
        System.out.println("Beta" + h);
        return h;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Baap b = new Beta();
        System.out.println(b.h + "," + b.geth());
        Baap bb = (Beta) b;
        System.out.println(bb.h + "," + bb.geth());
    }
}
```

The output of this code is

```
Beta44 
4,44 
Beta44 
4,44
```

I do not understand the order of the output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [basic java code to understand inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862464/basic-java-code-to-understand-inheritance)

Comment: Looks like a dup to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println(b.h + "," + b.geth());`

In this to print out the result, it needs to evaluate what is `b.geth()`. And hence ends up printing `Beta44` first and later `4,44`

Similar thing is happening with statement: `System.out.println(bb.h + "," + bb.geth());`

Answer (score 0):

It first evaluates the expression in println() statement, because of that Beta44 gets printed first. then it starts printing values in println statement from left to right , then print 4,44. it prints 4 because the instance variable is of Baap type. So, it picks the value of variable defined in Baap class.

Hope it will help.